# Laravel 6/7 deleting entity with validation

Tags: laravel, controller, conditional-statements, destroy

Guys.

I want to permit deletion only if some condition is true, like the code below. How can I do that?

```
public function destroy(Customer $customer) {
    if( ! $customer->is_special() ) {
        $customer->delete();
        return redirect( route( 'customer.index' ) );
    }

    // Else return some error message to the user, something like this
    return error('You cannot delete this customer.'); 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of expertise coming but not getting your question. For this reason your view is getting higher. But no response from expertise. 
Hard to get your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this `is_special` function in your  `Customer` Model. you can follow this code..

```
public function is_special()
{
    // return true or false  based on your condition;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Raw. Thank you for your help. I'm not concerned about the validations, but how can I return the error to the user, like the Validate method ( $request->validate( $rules, $messages ) ) does. I putted the method "Error", but it's only an example of how I want to do. Does exists something like that?